# Spring 3.2 + Quartz 2.1.7 issue

Tags: eclipse, spring, quartz-scheduler

I updated quartz from 1.8.6 to 2.1.7 couple days before and since then I couldn't start tomcat locally.  Always get following error:

```
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: class org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SimpleTriggerBean has interface org.quartz.SimpleTrigger as super class
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2820)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1150)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1645)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1523)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.checkHandlesTypes(ContextConfig.java:2006)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsStream(ContextConfig.java:1969)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsJar(ContextConfig.java:1858)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsUrl(ContextConfig.java:1826)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotations(ContextConfig.java:1812)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1306)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:896)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:322)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:89)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5103)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1033)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:774)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1033)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:621)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:322)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:450)
```

But I don't have "SimpleTriggerBean" in my code or configuration files.  I am using STS 3.2.  Can anyone help me?  Thanks.

Comment: I've tried re-install sts, but no luck.

Comment: I still get this error.

    public interface SimpleTrigger extends Trigger


and

    public class SimpleTriggerBean extends SimpleTrigger

Spring 3.2.4 says SimpleTrigger is a "class", but Quartz 2.2.1 says its an interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update tomcat fro 7.0.17 to 7.0.39 solves the issue.